# How structs are saved in memory C

Tags: c, windows

How structs in C are saved in the memory?

Why sometimes the struct length in the memory is bigger
than expected?

Comment: do you have an example ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

Comment: maybe you have low expectations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's called [data structure alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).

Although not a perfect duplicate, you can find a good explanation of this in C at [Structure padding and packing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4306186/structure-padding-and-structure-packing)

Answer (score 0):

- Structs are stored as a concatenation of the variables they are declared to contain.
- The variables are stored in the order they are declared. The address of the beginning of the struct is the address of the beginning of the first variable it contains.
- There may be a gap between the rest of the variables in the struct memory layout (or even at the end of the struct). This is done to [align the variables to memory addresses](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/) from which they can be fetched.

  - Some architectures can only fetch aligned data.
  - Most architectures that can fetch unaligned data, suffer a performance penalty when doing so.